# Count the size and rows of the tables in a database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a query to list the sizes of the tables and number of rows of the tables inside a database.

This is my query so far: -

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows
    ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS `Size (GB)`
    FROM 
      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    ORDER BY,
      (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)
    DESC
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db';
```

But i keep getting a syntax issue. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  TABLE_NAME AS `Table`,
  table_rows,
  ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024 ) AS `Size (MB)`
FROM
  information_schema.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your-db'
ORDER BY
  (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)
DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This did the job for me.